# Automatic image renaming based on title

Tags: customization, attachments, file-manager

Is there a plugin or a "hack" that can help me do this? I have spent hours try to figure this out so I would greatly appreciate nay help. I have WP 3.1 running php5 Thanks!

eg.: **postitle_image-ID.jpg**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hook into the filter `'sanitize_file_name'`. See my [plugin Germanix URL](https://github.com/toscho/Germanix-WordPress-Plugin/blob/master/germanix_url.php) for a working example.

A plugin doing this is [Rename Media](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rename-media/).

Comment: i search for a plugin, that renames the files during upload.

Comment: @msec I made an update to my answer and recommended a plugin.

Answer (score 1):

There is also [Media File Renamer](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/media-file-renamer/), and it does a bit more than Rename Media.